# Отличия между стандартным WebBrowser и WebView2, CefSharp

Tags: c#, wpf, cefsharp

В чем различие? Что быстрее работает, что удобнее?

Comment: `WebBrowser` - устаревший компонент, который основан на IE, он не поддерживает многие современные стандартны. `WebView2` - Современный компонент от самих Microsoft, который основан на Microsoft Edge. `CefSharp` - обертка над Chromium Embedded, грубо говоря полноценный браузер. Ну и тут сами понимаете, 1-й смысла нету использовать, а 2-й и 3-й основаны на одном и том же Chromium, только от разных авторов. Если выбирать, то я больше доверяю официальным компонентам, которые продуманы самими создателями языка C#, ну а это WebView2, но он вроде не является прям "полноценным браузером".

Comment: если вы пишете новое приложение, то смысла связываться с морально устаревшим WebBrowser нет

Comment: Ответ прост: если можете WebView2 - используйте, если не можете, берите CEF. WebBrowser закопайте обратно туда, где откопали.

Comment: какой из них быстрее? WebView2 или CefShapr?

Comment: Что быстрее Microsoft Edge или Chrome? Это если брать в расчет то, что ядро у них одинаковое - Chromium, над которым работает и Microsoft и Google вместе. Вы не на скорость смотрите, а на то, как они распросраняются. Вот CefSharp - это грубо говоря у вас в проекте будет лежать рядом полноценный браузер, со своими языками, компонентами, и всем всем всем другим. WebView2 - это компонент, который использует уже возможности предустановленные в OS, в проекте у вас будет всего несколько библиотек. Также смотрите на взаимодействие, CefSharp сложнее, его надо правильно инициализировать.

Comment: ну если сложнее это точно не для меня, та и полноценный браузер мне не нужен, все что мне нужно, это Монако, что бы вставлять туда скрипт, и инжектить его в игру, возможно еще что то, но полноценный я не думаю что мне нужен, я видел один пример очень похож на мою идею. но там отдельный класс, где скорее всего устанавливается тема, инитилизация и прочее, наверное это апи типо. Единственное что мне не понравилось, так это при открытии нового таба, на пол секунды там белый фон, а не сразу Монако, и еще я не понимаю как оно в основном окне иницилизируется, потому что там система табов еще

Comment: но я еще особо в этом не разобрался, табы то позже, поэтому думаю сначала надо с браузером разобраться, и в том примере используется Dragablz в качестве табов, а я планирую сделать через обычный таб контрол. там при иницилиазии используется метод, который создает таб, а в самом методе этот код "this.EditorSource = new WebViewA() ((HwndHost)this.EditorSource).UpdateWindowPos();" а дальше скорее всего не совсем относится к инициилизации браузера